# $K$-automorphisms permuting the roots of $f$ in $L$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, field-theory, galois-theory, splitting-field

Let $L$ be a splitting field of $f$ over $K$, with $\text{deg}(f) = n$. Prove that every $K$-automorphism of $L$ permutes the roots of $f$ in L.

I am a little confused with this question. I know that a $K$-automorphism is a map $\psi: L \rightarrow L$ which is a bijective isomoprhism. Furthermore I know that $f = \prod_{i=1}^{n} (X - \alpha_{i}) \in L[X]$. I have read in another post that under the automorphism it must hold that $\psi(\prod_{j=1}^{n} (\alpha_{j})) = \prod_{j=1}^{n} \alpha_{j}$, and from this one can deduce that the automorphism permutes the roots of $f$ in $L$. However, I don't really understand this step and why this equality must hold. If anybody could help me into the right direction I would appreciate that.

Comment: I can't see why $\psi(\prod_{j=1}^{n} (\alpha_{j})) = \prod_{j=1}^{n} \alpha_{j}$ implies that the automorphism permutes the roots in $L$ (though it is correct). However, the standard way to see this is to argue as follows: if $\alpha$ is a root of $f \in K[x]$, then $0 = f(\alpha) = \sum_i a_i \alpha^i$, for some $a_i \in K$. Then $0 = \psi(f(\alpha)) = \sum_i a_i \psi(\alpha)^i = f(\psi(\alpha))$, so $\psi(\alpha)$ is too a root of $f$.

Comment: This is an answer to the question, not just a comment. Please post your answer as an answer. This brings extra visibility to the answer und puts the question off the unanswered list (otherwise it will be bumped up periodically). Also notice that comments are not indexed by the full text search, don't have any revision history, can only be edited for 5 minutes and allow only limited markup. Comments should only be used to clarify, not answer the problem. See [How do comments work](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19756/how-do-comments-work) for more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't see why $\psi(\prod_{j=1}^{n} (\alpha_{j})) = \prod_{j=1}^{n} \alpha_{j}$ implies that the automorphism permutes the roots in $L$ (though it is correct). However, the standard way to argue as follows: if $\alpha$ is a root of $f \in K[x]$, then $0 = f(\alpha) = \sum_i a_i \alpha^i$ for some $a_i \in K$. Then
$$
0 = \psi(f(\alpha)) = \sum_i a_i \psi(\alpha)^i = f(\psi(\alpha))
$$
so $\psi(\alpha)$ is too a root of $f$.